# Simple mouse for big palms

Tags: pc, mice

I've above average sized palms.

I'm looking for a simple mouse which I can use comfortably for my daily purpose. And which can last longer than 1 year. In past I've tried a few big ones but they turned out to be useless after sometime due to left click problems.

I prefer wireless, but if wired have better option, then I'll not mind.

My daily average mouse usage is 4-5 hours.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that you can solve your ergonomic considerations with a trackball type input device. Logitech has been making the TrackMan Marble for many years. The device provides a rest for your palm and does not move. The ball (marble) is under one's thumb (right handed people only) while the mouse buttons fall to the proper locations for left and right clicking and mouse wheel action.

[image: trackman marble]

The above image is from the Office Depot web site, but Amazon and other sources of this device abound. The image is of a wireless version and I did not search for the wired type.

I've worn out about three of these over the last few decades, mostly the mouse buttons. They either fail to click or register a double click when one desires a single click.

Because the base remains stationary, it's also easier on your elbow and shoulder, if one is prone to repetitive stress injury.

There are other manufacturers of similar designs, but my experience (all good) is with the genuine Logitech product.

Answer (score 0):

WHITE SHARK MIYAMOTO is the best mouse for 2D and 3D design on the market - even much more expensive competitors don't have programmable buttons below and above the thumb and that's the best thing about this mouse! It would be perfect if it had an extra button for the index finger (in addition to the wheel). In terms of ergonomics, it's perfect for my hand, but for smaller hands and fatter fingers, it might not be recommended... A slightly smaller version should be made for smaller hands.
I used to use the DELUXE M910 WIRED (wireless version does not have the possibility of programmable keys) but unfortunately it is no longer available on the market.